# Using external functions in C - two .c files

Tags: c, netbeans, header-files

I am using net beans, and am trying to define function in an external C file, and use them in my main C file. It seems like the linker isn't working or something, as I am getting a build error:

> undefined reference to `setPixel'

The file containing my functions is myLib.c. The file that I am calling the function in is main.c

Both of these files `#include myLib.h` which contains the function prototypes for the functions within myLib.c

I shouldn't be getting this error, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the linker is linking both OBJ files?

Answer (score 2):

What does your compile command look like?  Obviously myLib.c will need compiling or the link will fail..

```
gcc main.c myLib.c
```